# Crackling sounds when both speakers are connected?

Tags: amplifier, speakers

I have finished my amplifier using the [LA4597](https://www.promelec.ru/pdf/la4597.pdf) chip following the schematic below.  So far everything's working fine.

However, I noticed something. Some songs crackle the speakers (probably because of their frequencies). But if I disconnect one speaker, the crackling sounds disappear on the other. I tested it to both of the speakers to check if one of them is blown or damaged but nope, both speakers sounded clean whenever the other one is disconnected. Btw, the volume was the same on every test that I did.

What is happening? Can this be resolved?

[image: 2]

Comment: Show the schematic!

Comment: Are the inputs connected to your audio source through 10uF capacitors? What is the AC input voltage reaching each channel? It helps to have a frequency generator for testing.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Done.

Comment: My first guess is your power supply cannot supply the current to drive both speakers. Does it happen only at high volume?

Comment: @rdtsc There are no capacitors from the amplifier inputs going to the audio source. I'm using a 12V DC supply.

Comment: @Janka Half-yes. Some songs doesn't crackle the speakers and they're even louder than the songs that do.

Comment: Perceived loudness doesn't necessarily equate to power needed. Also 12VDC doesn't say anything about the power it can deliver, What amp can it support?

Comment: So it means switching to a higher current supply voltage?

Comment: Put 10uF caps between both inputs and see if it helps.

Comment: @rdtsc Which caps should I use?

Comment: Almost any type of small, 10uF capacitor will work. Aluminum electrolytic would be fine, pick one which is "bipolar" or "unpolarized" for best results, like a Nichicon UES1E100MDM1TD or Panasonic ECE-A1CN100U, etc. Avoid tantalum.  Reason why is, there could be a DC offset to the signal you are feeding the amp, causing it to "clip."

Comment: @rdtsc What if I also added 1:1 audio transformers (isolators) before the caps?

Comment: Likely unnecessary.

Comment: @rdtsc I tried the capacitors. It did nothing.